# getClusters() returning array of length 0

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(30,
      40);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
var arr = markerCluster.getClusters();
alert(arr.length);
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    console.log(arr[i].getCenter());
}
```

The above code is returning array on length 0. Why is getClusters() not working?

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason. I need to wait for some time before markerCluster is created completely.Just changed this part below.

```
setTimeout(function() {
        var arr = markerCluster.getClusters();
        alert(arr.length);
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            console.log(arr[i].getCenter());
        }   
    },2000);
```